# Getting data in seconds, want to calculate hours, minutes & seconds

Tags: android, apache-flex

I'm getting a data which contains a certain number.

I need to find how many hours, minutes and seconds it stands for.

for example:

I'm getting the number 248 which means:

00 hours : 04 minutes : 08 seconds

Any ideas would be really apprieciated!

Comment: confusing.. sounds like special rules you need to implement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Determine hours, minutes and seconds like this:

```
int hours = (int) (time / 3600);
int minutes = ((int) (time / 60)) % 60;
int seconds = time % 60;
```

Alternatively, you can determine minutes like this once you know the hours:

```
int minutes = (int) ((time - hours * 3600) / 60));
```

Comment: FYI, floor means 'round down to the nearest integer', just as `(int) number` does in Java. There is also a `Math.floor()` function which returns a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to multiple it to milisec.
Like 248*1000;
Then Date d = new Date(248*1000);
And youll have data object.
d.getHours(). for example
also you can use SimpleDateFormat. Which can format data with some pattern and output it to string
Like yyyy-MM-hh HH:mm

Comment: Nice approach, let the standard libraries do the job.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define first, how this number is build up, e.g. why it can not stand for

00 hours, 02 minutes and 48 sseconds

Comment: I know for a fact the calculation is based on SECONDS, so it has to be 00:04:08

Comment: ahh, sorry, then the answer from "the nail" is the right one :). sorry. though you might want to have the minutes < 60, so you need to use "%" in minutes as well.

Comment: Heh I had the same at first. Even removed a nonsense comment for that :-)